# QlikView Columns Transformation

Tags: qlikview

Now i have the following data which is a result of a pivot table:

```
ID  |  Level 1  |  Level 2  |  Level 3
01  |     5     |     4     |     0
02  |     1     |     0     |     6
03  |     8     |     3     |     1
```

Can i visualise this information on a stacked chart in qlikview with X-Axis showing Level 1, Level 2, Level 3? The vertical axis will show the values in each of the level. Each bar will be stacked with the different IDs in different colors. I want to keep the dataset to be in this format.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the data in that format? Do you mean in the source data or within QlikView itself? I'd suggest looking into the `crosstable` function - that will spin the data out of the pivot format and into a more transactional table which QlikView works with much better... but if there's a reason you can't do that, then it won't help you much!

Answer (score 3):

Create a `bar chart`; have two dimensions (The Level-dimension and ID). Use the same expression. In the tab `Style` select "Stacked" as Subtype.

[image: Result]

I used sum(Value) with the following test data.

```
data:
load * inline [
ID, Dim, Value
1, Level1, 5
1, Level2, 4
1, Level3, 0
2, Level1, 1
2, Level2, 0
2, Level3, 6
3, Level1, 8
3, Level2, 3
3, Level3, 1
];
```